# Better way to say "at first sight"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I have draft where I want to say something like," At first sight, the problem seems intractable, but a careful analysis shows ..."

I feel "at first sight" seems a bit un-academic. Is there a better way to say the same thing?

Comment: Simply "at first". Not only is that more formal, but you already have it followed by *seems* anyway, which already implies sight. No need to pile up redundancies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "***Initially***, the problem seems intractable,..."

or for a more formal version, if that is the case:

> ***"Upon initial review,...***
>
> or
>
> ***"Upon initial inspection,..."***

Answer (score 0):

Consider *at first glance* and *at first blush*.

> [**at first glance**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glance) and at first blush: when first examined; at an early stage.

Alternately, how about "on first consideration?"

Answer (score 0):

Other common expressions  are:

**At first** the problem seems...

**At the beginning** the problem seems...

**The first impression** is that the problem seems..

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

**Distantly, Remotely**.
These adverbs are also considered.

Answer (score 0):

I think using "At first sight" or something similiar is particularly bad in an academic framework because it contradicts the scientific method. Science is not "first-sight" based but relies on careful and thorough examination.

Essentially what you are saying is: "From an un-academic point of view it seems like 
X but when seen from a scientific approach it is actually Y." But then the question arises why you would even state the unacademic approach. I guess what you want to say is that your results are against intuition, this is imho a much more powerful statement than at first sight. It implies that a preliminary analysis has already taken place whereas jumping to conclusions "at first sight" seems kind of lazy.

I think a way to regard this is to actually state the intuition behind the "first sight" conclusion. Something like "It may seem intuitive to think that X implies Y. However our research shows that this general relationship does not always hold true."

Answer (score 0):

Kristina's **"initially"** is what I would choose.

However **"superficially"** is what I would use if I wanted to convey that it needs a more careful, conscientious, expert or deeper investigation rather then merely a slightly longer one.